# How to open, copy, paste and close from the last two excel files in a folder

Tags: excel

I have the code below and would like to make it open the latest two xls files (by date modified) rather than just the latest, paste the data from the older of the two into the workbook (starting in cell A1) and the newer of the two into the workbook (starting in the next available row), and then close both worksheets. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim fso, fol, fil
Dim wkbSource As Workbook, wkbData As Workbook

Dim fileData As Date
Dim fileName As String, strExtension As String

Set wkbSource = ActiveWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Stuar\OneDrive\Documents\Boards")

fileData = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)

    For Each fil In fol.Files

        strExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fil.Path)
        If Left$(strExtension, 3) = "xls" Then

            If (fil.DateLastModified > fileData) Then
                fileData = fil.DateLastModified
                fileName = fil.Path
            End If

        End If

    Next fil

Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(fileName, , True)

wkbData.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
wkbSource.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wkbData.Close

Set fso = Nothing
Set fol = Nothing
Set flc = Nothing
Set wkbData = Nothing
End Sub
```